# Mule: transactional scope can't be adjacent to async scope

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, mule

I have a flow that makes two calls to a database to insert data, and one call to a stored procedure on another database. I would like the two insert calls to be processed as a transaction, i.e. either they both insert or neither does. I would also like the call to the stored procedure to be asynchronous, as I don't need to wait for a response and any errors during the stored procedure call should not impact the main message processing. Here's how I configured my flow:

```
<flow name="saveBrowser" doc:name="saveBrowser" >
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${my.host}" port="${my.port}"  path="Browser/Save" doc:name="/Browser/Save" />

...assorted transformations...
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to BrowserData" returnClass="com.mycompany.BrowserData"/>

<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="saveBrowser" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="firstJdbcConnector" doc:name="INSERT Browser"/>  
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="saveBrowserExtended" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="firstJdbcConnector" doc:name="INSERT BrowserExtended"/>       
</transactional>

<async doc:name="Async">
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="storedProcedureBrowser" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="secondJdbcConnector" doc:name="Stored Proc">
        <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
</async>

<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="BrowserData to JSON" sourceClass="com.mycompany.BrowserData" />
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
    ...
</catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

The error I get when I send a request to this flow, however, is that async scope can't be used with transactions. The documentation for transactional scope says, "You cannot build an asynchronous flow inside a transaction." However, the async scope is not within the transactional scope. It's adjacent but not within its scope. Why is this a problem?

I worked around this by passing the message to a separate flow containing the async scope and stored procedure call, via VM endpoints. If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know.

I'm in community edition, FYI.

Comment: Looks like a bug IMO: you're outside of the transactional boundary so async should work. Worth a JIRA!

Comment: +1. Same here. I have a flow with a transaction to update two tables. In the Catch Exception strategy, I am calling another flow to send email notification within async scope. I am getting same error. async is not even adjacent to the transactional scope. Using mule 3.8.5

Comment: Looks like you could be hitting MULE-14946 https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-14946